# Creating multiple consecutive output tables

Tags: r

I am attempting to write out hundreds of tables in R that follow a simple consecutive numerical sequence. I'm assuming this must be very simple but can't find a straightforward answer anywhere. My data takes the form:

```
write.table(file1, file="C:/.../file1.txt", sep="\t")
write.table(file2, file="C:/.../file2.txt", sep="\t")
write.table(file3, file="C:/.../file3.txt", sep="\t")
etc...
```

Any simple solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command `get()`

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  write.table(get(paste0("file", i)), file=paste0("C:/.../file",i,".txt"), sep="\t")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable **files** that include all the files' names, where **files[1]** is **file1** and **files[2]** is **file2**,..etc.
And n is the number of files, you can use:

```
for (i in 1:n){
        write.table(files[i], file=paste0("C:/.../file",i,".txt"), sep="\t")

}
```

Comment: Solution works efficiently and nicely - thanks guys!